# choose a specific set of values from xml using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

So I wanna choose a specific set of values from my xml file and print that into a dropdown box inside a html file using jQuery and AJAX.

As it is now it will print out everything that has the node 'stader' which is what it's supposed to do at the moment, but I only want it to print out the set of 'stader' which resides under node 'name' and that node 'name' has a unique ID which I want to match with the ID given from the dropdown.

The whole code does this - It looks at the XML file and takes the data from it and if it's a success it will run through all the nodes 'name' and take the id and a name that will be printed into the first dropdown box. Then it checks for any change and options selected which then runs the other half of the code where I wanna populate the second select/dropdown box(ID=landskap-stader) with all the citys/stader that is under that specific ID(under the node 'name' with the same ID) which was taken from the first dropdown box as it changed the selection.

I hope someone understands what I'm saying with all this nonsense. Sorry about the bad english/grammar and thanks in advanced.

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery, AJAX, XML</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formul&auml;r</legend>
            V&auml;lj ditt landskap: <select id="landskap"><option>V&auml;lj landskap</option></select><br />
            Gatuadress: <input type="text" /><br />
            Postnummer: <input type="text" /><br />
            <span id="stad-namn">?</span> <select id="landskap-stader"></select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the jQuery/AJAX code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('namn').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var nID = id;
                var aName = $(this).attr('landname');
                $('<option id="'+id+'">'+aName+'</option>').appendTo('#landskap');
                $("#landskap").change(function() {
                    $("#landskap option:selected").each(function() {
                        var landID = $(this).attr('id');
                        $(xml).find('namn').each(function() {
                            id = $(this).attr('id');
                            var select = $('#landskap-stader');
                            //var stader = $(this).find('stader').text();
                            if(landID == id) {
                                var bName = $(this).attr('landname');
                                $("#stad-namn").html(landID+'   '+bName+': ');

                                var optionsHtml = new Array();
                                $('stader', xml).each(function() {
                                    if(nID === landID) {
                                        var stader = $(this).text();
                                        optionsHtml.push('<option id="'+id+'">'+stader+'</option>');
                                    }
                                });
                                optionsHtml = optionsHtml.join('');
                                select.append(optionsHtml);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the XML file(There are alot of entrys so not posting everything, but you get the point):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sverige>
    <landskap>
        <namn id="1" landname="Blekinge">
                <stader>Karlskrona</stader>
                <stader>Karlshamn</stader>
                <stader>Ronneby</stader>
                <stader>Sölvesborg</stader>
                <stader>Olofström</stader>
        </namn>
        <namn id="2" landname="Bohuslän">
                <stader>Kungälv</stader>
                <stader>Lysekil</stader>
                <stader>Marstrand</stader>
                <stader>Strömstad</stader>
                <stader>Uddevalla</stader>
        </namn>
        <namn id="3" landname="Dalarna">
                <stader>Avesta</stader>
                <stader>Säter</stader>
                <stader>Ludvika</stader>
                <stader>Borlänge</stader>
                <stader>Falun</stader>
                <stader>Hedemora</stader>
        </namn>
        <namn id="4" landname="Dalsland">
                <stader>Åmål</stader>
                <stader>?</stader>
                <stader>?</stader>
                <stader>?</stader>
        </namn>
        <namn id="5" landname="Gotland">
                <stader>Visby</stader>
                <stader>?</stader>
                <stader>?</stader>
                <stader>?</stader>
        </namn>
```

**----------- EDIT -----------**

Since I can't answer my own question I'll just add what I did too fix it.

The only thing I had to change was the IF from

> if(nID === landID) {

to

> if(nID == landID) {

Also I added an select.empty() so it doesn't keep on adding too the dropdown menu, it takes new set of options each time.

```
$('stader', this).each(function() {
    if(nID == landID) {
        var stader = $(this).text();
        optionsHtml.push('<option id="'+id+'">'+stader+'</option>');
        select.empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: uhm ... have you ever looked at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: You should be able to "answer" it in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I had to change was the IF from

> if(nID === landID) {

to

> if(nID == landID) {

Also I added an select.empty() so it doesn't keep on adding too the dropdown menu, it takes new set of options each time.

```
$('stader', this).each(function() {
    if(nID == landID) {
        var stader = $(this).text();
        optionsHtml.push('<option id="'+id+'">'+stader+'</option>');
        select.empty();
    }
});
```